# Euclidean distance of Delaney triangulation - Scipy

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, delaunay

The `spatial` package imported from `Scipy` can measure the Euclidean distance between specified points. Is it possible to return the same measurement by using the `Delaunay` package? Using the `df` below, the average distance between all points is measured grouped by `Time`. However, I'm hoping to use Delaunay triangulation to measure the average distance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],                  
    'A_X' : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4], 
    'A_Y' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6],                         
        })

def make_points(x):
    return np.array(list(zip(x['A_X'], x['A_Y'])))

points = df.groupby("Time").apply(make_points)

for p in points:
    tri = Delaunay(p)
    ax.triplot(*p.T, tri.simplices)
```

Average distance between **all** points can be measured using below but I'm hoping to incorporate Delaunay.

```
 avg_dist = (df.groupby(['Time'])
             .apply(lambda x: spatial.distance.pdist
             (np.array(list(zip(x['A_X'], x['A_Y']))))
             .mean() if len(x) > 1 else 0)
             .reset_index()
             )
```

Intended Output:

```
   Time         0
0     1  1.082842
1     2  1.082842
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this function

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
    
def edges_with_no_replacement(points):
    
    # get the unique coordinates
    points = np.unique(points.loc[:,['A_X','A_Y']].values,return_index=False,axis=0)
    if len(points) <= 1: return 0
    # for two points, no triangle
    # I think return the distance between the two points make more sense? You can change the return value to zero.
    if len(points) == 2: return np.linalg.norm(points[0]-points[1])
    
    tri = Delaunay(points)
    triangles = tri.simplices
    # get all the unique edges 
    all_edges = set([tuple(sorted(edge)) for item in triangles for edge in combinations(item,2)])
    # compute the average dist 
    return np.mean([np.linalg.norm(points[edge[0]]-points[edge[1]]) for edge in all_edges])
```

This function will first find all the unique edges given triangles, then return the average length of the triangle edges. Apply this function

```
avg_dist = (df.groupby(['Time']).apply(edges_with_no_replacement).reset_index())
```

The output is

```
    Time    0
0   1   1.082843
1   2   1.082843
```

---

Note that the function `edges_with_no_replacement` will still throw `QhullError` if points are on the same line, for example

```
Delaunay(np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]))
```

So, you have to make sure the points are not on the same line.

Comment: Sorry just a quick one. I'll amend the question, but if I don't have enough points to calculate, I'm hoping to return a 0. But I'm getting an error: `QhullError: QH6214 qhull input error: not enough points(2) to construct initial simplex (need 4)

While executing:  | qhull d Qc Q12 Qz Qbb Qt
Options selected for Qhull 2019.1.r 2019/06/21:
  run-id 974469614  delaunay  Qcoplanar-keep  Q12-allow-wide  Qz-infinity-point
  Qbbound-last  Qtriangulate  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  _maxoutside  0`

Comment: @jonboy I have updated my post, the function `edges_with_no_replacement ` can now handle cases when there are only two unique points. But note that the function will still throw an error if the points are on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for this. So if 0-1 point, 0 is returned. If 2 points, the distance between them is returned. What do you mean by if points are on the same line sorry?

Comment: @jonboy You're welcome, in my updated post, I provide an example, `Delaunay` cannot find triangles if the points are on the same line (since there is no triangle after all). If you have such points in your dataset, you will also receive `QhullError`